# Authenticating a web service for transferring a file?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service that transfers a file, and i want to authenticate that the source of the transfer has access.  I authenticate all my clients by their user SID that gets pulled from AD, which is then encrypted and stored in a DB.  The problem i am running into is that the client transferring the file calls the service every 49152 bytes.  So basically I dont want it to make a DB call every time a new byte array comes in. Any idea how i could just make it call the DB once to verify the encrypted SID is authenticated once and then trust it until complete?

Here is my code:

```
 public class TransferFile : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        int Authenticated = 0;
        [WebMethod]
        public void WriteBinaryFile(string userSID, byte[] buffer, string FileName)
        {

            string ConnectionString = null;
            string DBServer = null;
            string AuthenticationMethod = null;
            string DB_U = null;
            string DB_P = null;
            string DBName = null;
            try
            {
                XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Program Files\SM\SM_DB_Config.xml");
                while (xmlReader.Read())
                {
                    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "DB_Server"))
                    {
                        string strUsername = null;
                        strUsername = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml().ToString();
                        if (strUsername.ToString() == "")
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DBServer = SpartaCrypto.SpartaDecryptAES(strUsername, "secretcode");
                        }
                    }
                    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "DB_Name"))
                    {
                        string strUsername = null;
                        strUsername = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml().ToString();
                        if (strUsername.ToString() == "")
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DBName = SpartaCrypto.SpartaDecryptAES(strUsername, "secretcode");
                        }
                    }
                    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "DB_AuthenticationMethod"))
                    {
                        string strUsername = null;
                        strUsername = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml().ToString();
                        if (strUsername.ToString() == "")
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AuthenticationMethod = SpartaCrypto.SpartaDecryptAES(strUsername, "secretcode");
                        }
                    }
                    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "DB_U"))
                    {
                        string strUsername = null;
                        strUsername = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml().ToString();
                        if (strUsername.ToString() == "")
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DB_U = SpartaCrypto.SpartaDecryptAES(strUsername, "secretcode");
                        }
                    }
                    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "DB_P"))
                    {
                        string strUsername = null;
                        strUsername = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml().ToString();
                        if (strUsername.ToString() == "")
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DB_P = SpartaCrypto.SpartaDecryptAES(strUsername, "secretcode");
                        }
                    }

                }
                xmlReader.Close();
                if (AuthenticationMethod == "Integrated")
                {
                    ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + DBServer + ";Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=" + DBName + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;";
                }
                else
                {
                    ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + DBServer + ";Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=" + DBName + ";User ID=" + DB_U + ";Password=" + DB_P;
                }
                String query = "SELECT COUNT(AD_SID) As ReturnCount FROM AD_Authorization WHERE AD_SID = ?";
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userSID", userSID.ToString());
                conn.Open();
                int returnCount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                conn.Close();
                if (returnCount >= 1)
                {
                    Authenticated = 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    Authenticated = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            if (Authenticated == 1)
            {
                string PathName = @"C:\Test\";


                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(PathName + FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is hitting the db frequently, I would suggest you cache the SID in your webservice as authenticated. Whenever you get a request, check if the value exists in the cache and if it is not there, then hit the db. Also you should set a optimal time for expiration.

You could use `HttpRuntime.Cache` for this purpose.

Code to set the value in Cache

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(userSID, 1, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0))
```

Code to get the value from Cache

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(userSID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save the first result in the **ASP.NET Cache**. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480499.aspx

You can save objects (like the validation variable) in cache like this:

```
var Authenticated = ... (the value that you already have)

HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
                    "myAuthenticatedCacheKey",
                    Authenticated,
                    null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), // 10 minutes expiration
                    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration
                    );
```

And you can recover them like this:

```
var Authenticated = HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("myAuthenticatedCacheKey");
```

Another way to go could be using the **Application object** (The same as the Session object but with an application scope and it is shared between all the sessions). You can store and retrieve objects from the Application scope like the following:

```
Session("myAuthenticatedSessionKey") = Authenticated;
...
var Authenticated = Session("myAuthenticatedSessionKey");
```

Please notice that **you need to cast** the objects when retrieving them from Cache or Application objects.